# Wait until page is fully loaded with selenium and intern js

Tags: selenium, wait, intern

I am trying to create a UI automation test with intern js , but i m getting problem on waiting until the page is fully loaded. My code starts searching for element before the page is loaded. Can some one help me on this.

My code:

```
define([
'intern!object',
'intern/chai!assert',
'Automation/ConfigFiles/dataurl',
'Automation/pages/login/loginpage',
'intern/dojo/node!fs',
'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil'
 ], function (registerSuite, assert,dataurl, LoginPage,fs,pollUntil) {
registerSuite(function () {
    var loginPage;
    var values;
    return {

        setup: function () {
            var data = fs.readFileSync(loginpage, 'utf8');
            json=JSON.parse(data);
            console.log('###########Setting Up Login Page Test##########')
            this.remote
                .get(require.toUrl(json.locator.URL))
           .then(pollUntil(this.remote.findById('uname').isDisplayed(),6000)// here i want to wait until page is loaded
        .waitForDeletedByClassName('loading').end().sleep(600000)// here i want to wait until loading component is disappered



            values = json.values;
            loginPage = new LoginPage(this.remote,json.locator);

        },

        'successful login': function () {
            console.log('##############Login Success Test############')
            return loginPage
                .login(values.unamevalue,values.pwdvalue)

        },

        // …additional tests…
    };
  });
});
```

I m trying to use pollUntil . But I m not sure weather I should use it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pollUntil` is a good thing to use here, but it doesn't look like you're actually waiting for polling to finish. Your `setup` method needs to return the command chain that includes `pollUntil` so that Intern will know it needs to wait, something like:

```
var setupPromise = this.remote
    .get(require.toUrl(json.locator.URL))...
values = json.values;
loginPage = new LoginPage(this.remote, json.locator);
return setupPromise;
```

Alternatively, you could pass your LoginPage class the chain:

```
var setupPromise = this.remote
    .get(require.toUrl(json.locator.URL))...
values = json.values;
loginPage = new LoginPage(setupPromise, json.locator);
```

In this case Intern won't wait for setup to complete, but your LoginPage code will implicitly wait for the setupPromise to complete before doing anything else. While this will work, the intent isn't as clear as in the previous example (e.g., that Intern should wait for some setup process to complete before proceeding).

Comment: Thanks @jason0x43 just figured out that i need to return the promise to make may code  wait. I'm accepting this as answer.